# Argument of type 'NgElementConstructor<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-elements

I'm getting a strange warning in VSCode( 1.44.0-insider ) with Angular9 in creating Angular Elements:

```
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const helloElement = createCustomElement(HelloComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('my-hello', helloElement);
  }
  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

type of `helloElement` is not accepted with an error message from typescript:

> Argument of type 'NgElementConstructor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems it will be fixed with the next release: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/35864

You can already test it for your project by updating to the next release (9.1.0-next.4).

```sh
ng update @angular/core --next
```

Comment: use "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core" instead to avoid errors if installed packages are incompatible with the update.