# Reusable custom element angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a custom element in angular for reuse in other projects, so I need to be able to distribute it.

Currently, I am following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-reusable-component-with-angular-elements).
Now I am trying to make `app.module.ts` so that my dossier component becomes an element I can use.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DossierComponent } from './dossier/dossier.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DossierComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    DossierComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector ) {
    const dossier = createCustomElement(DossierComponent, { injector });
    customElements.define('dossier', dossier);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {

  }
}
```

Now this line in the code 'customElements.define('dossier', **dossier**);' gives this error

```
Argument of type 'NgElementConstructor<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'
```

I have no clue what causes this. Maybe someone on here knows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument of type 'NgElementConstructor<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633792/argument-of-type-ngelementconstructorunknown-is-not-assignable-to-parameter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633792/argument-of-type-ngelementconstructorunknown-is-not-assignable-to-parameter Thanks do Edric