# Unable to create Custom Angular Element

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a custom Component which is being registered to module like this. 
**app.module.ts**

```
import { createCustomElement } from "@angular/elements";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ExtensionComponent],
  entryComponents: [ExtensionComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const extension = createCustomElement(ExtensionComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('caas-extension', extension);
  }
}
```

For this i am getting an error in the last line where i define the custom element "extension".
**Error**

```
Argument of type 'NgElementConstructor<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'.
```

I have updated cli version as well as suggested in other answer on the similar issue. Below are my version details

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.0-rc.0
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 9.1.0-rc.2
```

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633792/argument-of-type-ngelementconstructorunknown-is-not-assignable-to-parameter ?

Comment: Yes, I did the same . but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. To overcome this issue, I undo my changes on git to updated versions on package.json file and  re-updated it with following command:
ng update @angular/core --next

I hope this works for you too.